# OpenGL - Simple 2D Texture Not Being Displayed

Tags: c++, opengl-es, textures

I have written a very simple OpenGL program using glfw and glew. It compiles fine and runs, but the simple texture I am passing to the fragment shader is not being displayed.

The only geometry is a single quad.

I am only trying to display a single solid color, the first element of the texture. I know that the fragment shader works at all because I can display a solid color without the texture:

```
#version 320 es
mediump out vec4 color;
precision mediump float;
precision mediump sampler2D;

in vec2 texCoord;
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main() {
    color = vec4(0.5, 0.75, 0.5, 1.0);
}
```

[image: Simple fragment shader, solid color works]

However, when I use the texture sampler I get nothing, like the sampler is sampling only 0s (changing only `main()`):

```
void main() {
    color = vec4(texture(tex, vec2(0, 0)).rgb, 1);
}
```

[image]

I am populating and generating the texture in what I believe is the correct manner (`TEX_SIZE` is defined as `#define TEX_SIZE (32*32)`):

```
//Texture Data
GLfloat texData[TEX_SIZE * 3] = {1.0};

//Create texture
GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 32, 32, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, texData);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_REPEAT);
```

And here is the entire draw loop:

```
//Render loop
while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS
    && !glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(programID);

    //Texture
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "tex"), 0);

    //Draw the quad
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, gVertices);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, gIndices);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    if (glGetError()) {
        puts((char *)glewGetErrorString(glGetError()));
    }

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Why is this happening? I'm totally stuck.

EDIT: Changed the array initialization, as per suggestion:

```
//Texture Data
GLfloat texData[TEX_SIZE * 3];
for (int i = 0; i < TEX_SIZE * 3; i++) {
    texData[i] = 1.0;
}
```

There was no change. Output is still all black.

Comment: Do you bind the texture-unit 0 to `tex` in your shader?

Comment: @tkausl My whole frag shader is pasted above, so I guess not? How do I do that?

Comment: Your shader loading code is not, however. You do it the same way you'd set other uniforms, just set a int (`0` in this case) to the uniform `tex`. Your error-handling is broken by the way, it ignores the first error it sees.

Comment: @tkausl [here is my loading code](https://pastebin.com/FZjCbaNs). What function do I need to use to bind my uniform to 0?

Comment: `glUniform1i` to set a single int.

Comment: @tkausl But am I not already doing that in the render loop with `glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(programID, "tex"), 0);`?

Comment: You're right, didn't notice that line. You could try with a RGBA 32bit image format instead of your 3 floats per pixel, it might make a difference or might not, I've never worked with float images. Otherwise, [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/) can tell you whats really going on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183796/discussion-between-bpmw-and-tkausl).

Comment: @Rabbid76 the very first pixel is bottom left, hence it should be red.

Comment: @Rabbid76 that is a valid way to initialize an entire array to one value. It should populate the entire array with 1.0 EDIT: also my shader only samples the first value in the array, so the whole screen should be red if only the first value is red

Comment: @Rabbid76 [The first element corresponds to the lower left corner of the texture image. Subsequent elements progress left-to-right through the remaining texels in the lowest row of the texture image, and then in successively higher rows of the texture image. The final element corresponds to the upper right corner of the texture image.](http://docs.gl/gl3/glTexImage2D)

Comment: @Rabbid76 I changed the array initialization. The result is the same.

Comment: Is `tex` used in `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);` right before `glUniform1i`  in scope? Which value?

Comment: The initial value of `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. Since you don't generate mipmaps, change it: `glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 oh nice that fixed it! can you put that in the form of an answer so i can mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial value of `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`. But you don't generate mipmaps. This causes that the texture is not *complete*.

[OpenGL ES 3.2 Specification; 8.17 Texture Completeness; page 205](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/es_spec_3.2.pdf)

> A texture is said to be *complete* if all the texture images and texture parameters
>   required to utilize the texture for texture application are consistently defined.
>
> ... a texture is complete unless any of the following
>   conditions hold true:
>
> - The minification filter requires a mipmap (is neither `NEAREST` nor `LINEAR`),
>     and the texture is not mipmap complete.

Change the texture minification filter ([`glTexParameteri`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexParameter.xhtml)) to solve your issue:

e.g.

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Comment: You saved my life a year after this post.